# find() and Cursors problems: .toArray vs cursor.forEach method showing different results and an error "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cursor

Hi newbie here, with express i tried the .toArray method using the video database on localhost. This code works fine, i was able to display the data using handlebars as my template engine, each data shows the title, year and imdb in a bordered container:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', function(err, database){
    assert.equal(null,err);
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');

    var db = database.db('video');

    router.get('/', function(req,res){
        db.collection('movieDetails').find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
          res.render('home', {
              title: 'Movies',
              movieDetails: result
          });
          database.close();
        });
    });
});
```

however, using cursor method, i see no data but only the borders and the labels, And i get this error on bash shell "Can't set headers after they are sent." this is the code:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', function(err, database){
        assert.equal(null,err);
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');

        var db = database.db('video');

        router.get('/', function(req,res){
           var query = {};
           var cursor = db.collection('movieDetails').find(query);
           cursor.forEach(
               function(result){
                  res.render('home',{
                      title: 'Movies',
                      movieDetails: result
                  });
               },
               function(err){
                  assert.equal(err, null);
                  return database.close();
               }
           );
        });
    });
```

This is the code of my homepage using handlebars template engine:

```
{{#each movieDetails}}
    <div class="movie_data">
        <h5>{{this.title}}</h5>
        <p><strong>Year:</strong> {{this.year}} <strong>Imdb:</strong> {{this.imdb}}</p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Need help, i can't seem to figure out how to display the data using the cursor method, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a semantic difference between the two code snippets you have shared. The culprit is in the result handler.

In the first handler (the one as a callback into the `toArray` function) tells the library to give you the results in the form of an array. When you ask the express server to send a response, you are passing the whole array stored (the reference is stored in the `result` variable).

In the second handler, where you are using the cursor method, the `forEach` call tells the Mongo library to execute the callback for each element inside the cursor results. This means that if your query returns 5 movies, the callback will be executed 5 times. This also means that the `res.render` will try to execute 5 times. This will lead to the error you are seeing, as on the second iteration, the `res` instance you have a reference to would have already been sent.

As your handler inside Handlebars expects an array of movies, and the response you gave it was a single movie instance (remember the `forEach` method will pass each item of the collection individually to the callback inside the `result` parameter), your page won't render correctly.

I hope this helps you out. Good luck :)

Comment: Ok so it's best to use the .toArray instead of cursor? what if you have thousands of files which is more appropriate and how to use the cursor method the right way?

Comment: There is no "best" way per say - it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you know that the query is going to possibly return you thousands of records you can either use the `limit` method to constraint how many records are returned or narrow down the query itself.

It all depends on how you want your data to look, how your front-end consumes it and what your domain constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

this should work as you expect

```
router.get('/', function(req,res){
           var query = {};
           db.collection('movieDetails').find(query).toArray(function(err, result){
                res.render('home',{
                      title: 'Movies',
                      movieDetails: result
                  });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem trying to use `forEach()` and did a lot of looking for an answer but mostly the reply is "just use `toArray()`". But I wanted to use the "streaming batch of docs" that `forEach()` gives better efficiency right? wrong...

I see your using the same data from mongoUni, me too, I put a question up there and this is a breakdown of the best answer...

The efficiency only works for huge amount of results 250,000 for example but typically when rendering a template we may only need 50.

Using `forEach()` to return 50 results as actually less efficient than `toArray()` as it forces the cursor to do the iteration and array building.

`toArray()` basically implements an "async loop" which "iterates" the cursor content for you and only returns once that async iteration is complete. For a small batch results (using `limit()` in the query) `toArray()` is the best and really the only option.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info, Andew are you a student of MongoUni too? Finals now and haven't get passed Lab 1 cause i kept getting reference error: db is not defined.

Comment: @Twirlman yes I am... that final exam is really tough, it's taken me days. Lab 1 especially, just to get my head around the application i used this way to query the db  `this.db.collection("item").aggregate().toArray(function(err, docs){#codebloc_here})` hope thats not too late

Comment: yeah man same approach here, but haven't answered the 2 bonus Lab 6 and 7.. There's another class that will start on March 13, M121: The MongoDB Aggregation Framework